# Error When Added MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +2080169
   System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument) +106
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +32
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +7
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +11
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +174
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5102




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.42; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.42
```

What can i do to correct this?

Comment: I assume you did what the error message suggests - setting the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation property?

Answer (score 1):

The error contains enough information on what to, you can do either of the following:

**1. Add directive to Master Page**

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>
```

**2. Edit Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
  <pages enableEventValidation="true"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have multiple form-elements. Remove any form-element from content page.

Comment: This was my issue. Multiple <form> tags on the same WebForms page.